# forEach use in nslaoyutconstraints

Tags: swift, loops, foreach, nslayoutconstraint

I want my swift code to see if there is a way to use something similar to a for Each loop when creating constraints. Right now the code would not compile. Where $0 is would be b4 in a normal setting. If I could do something like this it would make my coding a lot efficient if I had to do this for multiple objects.

```
           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     [b4].forEach({ 
       


        $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLbl.bottomAnchor),
        $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b3.trailingAnchor),
        $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
        $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.25)

           })

           ])
```

Edit for something not working

```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      [b4].flatMap { [
          textBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        textBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        textBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.08),
        textBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),

            $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLbl.bottomAnchor),
            $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: undo.trailingAnchor),
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.25)

        ] }
    
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `flatMap`. For example, if you want to add the same constraints to `b4`, `b5`, `b6`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
    [b4, b5, b6].flatMap { [

        $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLbl.bottomAnchor),
        $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b3.trailingAnchor),
        $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
        $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.25)

    ] }
)
// call "activate" again to do the other constraints
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        textBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        textBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.08),
        textBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
    ])
```

You can also just do one call to `activate` if you use `+`, but I find this harder to read:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
    [b4, b5, b6].flatMap { [

        $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLbl.bottomAnchor),
        $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b3.trailingAnchor),
        $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
        $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.25)

    ] }
    + [ // here!
        textBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        textBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        textBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.08),
        textBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
    ]
)
```

Or, use a regular `for` loop and call `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` multiple times. *There is nothing wrong with that*:

```
for b in [b4, b5, b6] {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLbl.bottomAnchor),
        b.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b3.trailingAnchor),
        b.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.10),
        b.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.25)
    ])
}
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        textBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        textBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.08),
        textBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
    ])
```

But if you are going to add the same constraints to a bunch of views, they are going to be completely overlapping each other.

It seems like you might want to position these views horizontally in a line. I would using a [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) for this, rather than adding the constraints manually.

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedStackViews: [b3, b4, b5, b6])
stackView.axis = .horizontal
```

You can then add constraints to the stack view, and try experimenting with the `distribution` and `alignment` properties to get the desired result.

Comment: Your first example does not appear to work it is causing this error Cannot convert value of type '[NSLayoutConstraint]' to expected element type 'Array<NSLayoutConstraint>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'NSLayoutConstraint') on the flatMap line

Comment: @joebuck Please read the code again. You might have added some extra `[]` on the outside.

Comment: I see what your saying my nslaout constraint is like  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([. I need that though for the other constraints.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you edit your question to illustrate? @joebuck

Comment: @joebuck I understand that you have `activate([`. I want you to explain why you need `([`. What do you mean by "other constraints"? Can't you just add other constraints with another call to `activate`?

Comment: I added a another objects constrains so that is what I mean when i say other constraints. edited question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226019/discussion-between-sweeper-and-joe-buck).